# Dowloading data from quandl.com and want to know how I include my API key with my request?

Tags: python, api-key, quandl

I am downloading data from quandl.com with python and I have reached my limit with 50 downloads for today. Users with an account can exceed this limit which I already have an account set up. The error message say I need to put my api key with the request, but to my knowledge it does not say how??

This is the error message

```
quandl.errors.quandl_error.LimitExceededError: (Status 429) (Quandl Error QELx01) You have exceeded the anonymous user limit of 50 calls per day. To make more calls today, please register for a free Quandl account and then include your API key with your requests.
```

This is the code I am using it works except for request limit

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import pandas.io.data as web

symbols = ['BOE/XUDLTWD','BOE/XUDLCDS','tvix'] 



pnls = {}
for i in symbols:

    a = '/' in i

    if a == True:
        data = quandl.get(i ) 
        t = i.split('/')
        df1= pnls
        df1[str(t)] = data
        print(a)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's how to use your api key properly.

`data = Quandl.get('what', authtoken='your_api_key')`

Answer (score 0):

for API key you have to first login in quandl and after login, u will get your API Key.
then `data = Quandl.get('what', authtoken='your_api_key')` as above answer